Interesting behavior of a function in a 2D XY plane
Consider the function y =x^n/n! plotted for ( n = 2 ) to ( 20 ). Upon examination, it becomes evident that for certain larger values of ( n ) and ( y ), the gap between the graphs corresponding to two consecutive ( n ) remains approximately constant.
enter image description here

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
